# Return partial result in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running the following cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:Owner) WHERE n.identifier = "1234"
WITH n
MATCH (n)-[r:OWNS]->(:Thing) WHERE r.date < "2018-10-23"
RETURN n, max(DISTINCT r.date)
```

When a relationship with `date < "2018-10-23"` exists, this is fine, I get a tuple `(n, <the date>)` but if no relationship satisfies the constraint, how would I still return `n`. I'm guessing there is a way to return `(n, null)` but I can't figure out how to write the query that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:OWNS]->(:Thing) WHERE r.date < "2018-10-23"
```

Comment: Brilliant, that was almost too easy :)